# How to share group repository in GitLab 6.0.0

Tags: gitlab

I just installed GitLab 6.0.0 and I am now trying to create a group in order to share a common repository with other users. So I created the group and then added the users I want as owners of this group.

The problem is that the group members don't seem to be able to choose the corresponding namespace when they creating a new project.

Is this a bug? or am I missing something?

Any help is welcomed, thanks.

Best regards,
Michael Pinheiro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this bug: [issue 4900](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/4900)

workarounds:

> I should also mention that if User B now creates a Group Y, he is now able to create projects for Group X and Y. (which is a simple workaround)
>
> The other work-around is to have the user create the project in their personal namespace first, then when the repo is created go to `settings -> dangerous settings -> change namespace` option.

A patch should be proposed soon to fix that bug, which seems to be related to [`app/models/user.rb`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/25a723c3ae04c5818427682b2fbe97609a97f1ea/app/models/user.rb) ([lines 293-295](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/25a723c3ae04c5818427682b2fbe97609a97f1ea/app/models/user.rb#L293-L295) and [lines 331-333](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/25a723c3ae04c5818427682b2fbe97609a97f1ea/app/models/user.rb#L331-L333))